# Jaxb namespaces for java.util.Map properties

Tags: java, jaxb, jaxb2

I have a simple class that contains a hashmap:

```
@XmlRootElement()
public class Customer {

    private long id;
    private String name;

    private Map<String, String> attributes;

    public Map<String, String> getAttributes() {
        return attributes;
    }

    public void setAttributes(Map<String, String> attributes) {
        this.attributes = attributes;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc =
           JAXBContext.newInstance("com.rbccm.dbos.payments.dao.test");

        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setId(123);
        customer.setName("Jane Doe");

        HashMap<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<String, String>();
        attributes.put("a1", "v1");
        customer.setAttributes(attributes);


        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        m.marshal(customer, sw);
        System.out.println(sw.toString());

    }

}
```

The Main method produces the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:customer id="123" xmlns:ns2="http://www.example.org/package">
    <ns2:attributes>
        <entry>
            <key>a1</key>
            <value>v1</value>
        </entry>
    </ns2:attributes>
    <ns2:name>Jane Doe</ns2:name>
</ns2:customer>
```

The problem I have is that the namespace is dropped when outputting the hashmap.  What I would like to generate is xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:customer id="123" xmlns:ns2="http://www.example.org/package">
    <ns2:attributes>
        <ns2:entry>
            <ns2:key>a1</ns2:key>
            <ns2:value>v1</ns2:value>
        </ns2:entry>
    </ns2:attributes>
    <ns2:name>Jane Doe</ns2:name>
</ns2:customer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an [`XmlAdapter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html) with you `java.util.Map` property to get the namespace qualification you are looking for.

For an example of using `XmlAdapter` with `java.uti.Map` see:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/07/xmladapter-jaxbs-secret-weapon.html

For more info on JAXB and namespaces :

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html

---

**FYI**

I am considering adding an extension to [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) to better handle this scenario:

```
@XmlMap(wrapper="my-entry", key="@my-key", value="my-value")
public Map<String, PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers = new HashMap<String, PhoneNumber>();
```

The above annotation would correspond to the following XML:

```
<phoneNumbers>
    <my-entry my-key="work">
        <my-value>613-555-1111</value>
    </my-entry>
</phoneNumbers>
```

The key/value properties would be XPath statements, and the namespace information would follow what is done for other MOXy extensions (for an example see link below):

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/09/xpath-based-mapping-geocode-example.html

Enhancement Request

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/322423

Comment: Yes, that works.  But it looks like you have to create 3 extra classes for each type you want to use as a value in the hashmap.  With that kind of overhead its probably preferable to live with no namespace on the map elements. (The other link has been very helpful, you may have noticed that my question is 99% based on that example)

Comment: that extension looks very useful.  Would the schemagen task work with it too?

Comment: @Heathen - When we add it, it will definitely work with the `JAXBContext.genertateSchema()` method (http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/JAXB/GenerateSchema).  We have another enhancement request for adding an ant task for schema generation (https://bugs.eclipse.org/336076).