# Jaxb - Namespace problems with SchemaGen and java.util.Map

Tags: jaxb, jaxb2

When a class contains a java.util.Map, SchemaGen generates an xsd with a namespace on the Map elements.  However when the marshaller generates xml from the same class no namespace is [present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255380/jaxb-namespaces-for-java-util-map-properties).

This may be solvable with XmlAdapter however that seems to require the creation of 3 extra classes per Map.  As I have a large number of maps I don't want to go down this route.

Is there any way to get SchemaGen and the Marshaller to generate the same xml?

Example Classes and schemas:

Test1:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Test1 implements Serializable {

    private String field1;

    private Map<String, Test2> attributes;

    public Test1() {}

    public String getField1() {
        return field1;
    }

    public void setField1(String field1) {
        this.field1 = field1;
    }

    public Map<String, Test2> getAttributes() {
        return attributes;
    }

    public void setAttributes(Map<String, Test2> attributes) {
        this.attributes = attributes;
    }
}
```

Test2:

```
public class Test2 implements Serializable {

    private String name;
    private String value;

    public Test2() {
    }

    public Test2(String name, String value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

SchemaGen output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0" targetNamespace="http://testns" xmlns:tns="http://testns" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="test1" type="tns:test1"/>

  <xs:complexType name="test1">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="attributes">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="entry" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element name="key" minOccurs="0" type="xs:string"/>
                  <xs:element name="value" minOccurs="0" type="tns:test2"/>
                </xs:sequence>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="field1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="test2">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="value" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Xml that conforms to the schema.  (note. jaxb will not unmarshall this xml!)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns1:test1 
    xmlns:ns1="http://testns" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://testns ../build/schemas/schema1.xsd"
    >
    <ns1:attributes>
        <ns1:entry>
            <ns1:key>a1</ns1:key>
            <ns1:value>
                <ns1:name>a1</ns1:name>
                <ns1:value>v1</ns1:value>
            </ns1:value>
        </ns1:entry>
    </ns1:attributes>
    <ns1:field1>f1</ns1:field1>
</ns1:test1>
```

Xml that Jaxb produces. (note. It does not conform to the schema!)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:test1 xmlns:ns2="http://testns">
    <ns2:attributes>
        <entry>
            <key>a1</key>
            <value>
                <ns2:name>a1</ns2:name>
                <ns2:value>v1</ns2:value>
            </value>
        </entry>
    </ns2:attributes>
    <ns2:field1>f1</ns2:field1>
</ns2:test1>
```